# Android mockito Unit test can't resolve MockitoAnnotations.openMocks

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing, mvvm, mockito

When I am trying to write Unit test for my ViewModels using Mockito library, I  am not able to call openMocks MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this) funtion

I tried the following dependencies.

```
  testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.19.0"
  testImplementation "org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:2.19.0"
  testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:2.19.0"
  implementation 'androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.1.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

*Your version seems outdated.* Use the latest version of Mockito for Android

```
testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:3.11.2"
testImplementation "org.mockito.kotlin:mockito-kotlin:3.11.2"
```

Note: io.mockk:mockk can cause conflict with mockito, so could be that you need to remove it.